# "System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001" in count query

Tags: apex

I am getting this error in this line

```
list<AggregateResult> LstTicketPreEmpCases = new list<AggregateResult>();
        LstTicketPreEmpCases = [SELECT Highest_Charge_Level__c, count(id)NoofCharge,COUNT_DISTINCT(PreEmploy_Case__r.name)NoofCases FROM BGC_Criminal_Search_Record__c
        GROUP BY Highest_Charge_Level__c LIMIT 1000];
```

I have reduced limit to 10 but still I'm getting this error but when I'm using LIMIT 1 than it works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got error it was from visualforce page. I have fixed it by applying readOnly="true"

Answer (score 0):

Probably   **"COUNT_DISTINCT(PreEmploy_Case__r.name)"**  this is the cause of this issue --

Try putting some 'While Condition' for this "PreEmploy_Case__r" parent records in query (This might be fetching more than 50000 records), applying some while condition will reduce this count.

Comment: Do you mean a "Where" condition and not While?

Comment: Hello @Nilesh i have tried it after removing ,COUNT_DISTINCT(PreEmploy_Case__r.name)NoofCases but still it throws same exception at same line.

Comment: @Eric  - Yes Eric, I meant "where" not "While" sorry about that,    But Still it seem he is going through some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the above query, it is a good practice to analyze how many records have the same Highest_Charge_Level__c  in the BGC_Criminal_Search_Record__c object.  Looks most of the cases are associated with the single value or just a few bunch of Highest_Charge_Level__c values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i query this in developer class than it works fine but in class it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

You are using  LIMIT 1000 in the Aggregate Query which is the limit on number of records returned by Query not the number touched to get the aggregate result which in you case is greater than 50000.

The issue is that an aggregate query is considered to have accessed every record included in the aggregation. Thus the 50000 row limit isn't the number of records returned by the query, its the number of records used to get the aggregate result.

Queries that include aggregate functions are subject to the same governor limits as other SOQL queries for the total number of records returned. This limit includes any records included in the aggregation, not just the number of rows returned by the query. If you encounter this limit, you should add a condition to the WHERE clause to reduce the amount of records processed by the query.

You can also @readOnly annotation in order to increase the 50000 records limit.